# KNNImputer doesnt replace

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, knn

I try to replace 999999.0 in a table with KNNImputer and the same 999999.0- are in the exported csv files.

```
imputer = KNNImputer(missing_values=999999.0, n_neighbors=2, weights="uniform")
imputer.fit_transform(X)
```

I tried to rename to nan, np.nan but still KNNImputer doesnt replace them. There is no error message, the new CSV generated. I also tried to replace in the dateframe before to nan or np.nan but that is also not happening:

```
df.replace({999999:nan}, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution was to replace the '999999's with 'nan's while doing the csv import wtih "na_values=":

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8', engine='python', na_values='999999.0')
```